# Using value of user defined variable in another user defined variable in JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter

**Is there any possibility to pass a value of user defined variable in *another* user defined variable?** How to do this?

---

I've got a variable (name | value):

```
version | 5.6
```

and I want to use it in another one:

```
config | config_${version}.csv
```

[image]

It does not work because `${version}` is treated as a string not as variable.

I've tried it with `__eval` function (the same) and with `__P` (then value of variable `config` was config1.csv, so `${version}` was treated as a `1`.

---

I'm using JMeter 3.3.

Answer (score 3):

Notice the warning in [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables):

> the variables are not available for use until after the element has been processed, so you cannot reference variables that are defined in the same element. You can reference variables defined in earlier UDVs or on the Test Plan.

So you can declare version variable to `Test Plan` and call it using [__V](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function in User Defined Variables:

```
   ${__V(config_${version}.csv)}
```

Another option is to move to  [User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) with similar  usage of [__V](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function

> For defining variables during a test run, see User Parameters. UDVs are processed in the order they appear in the Plan, from top to bottom.

Note: `__P` is used for retrieving JMeter property and not variable

Comment: I think __V is not necessary when referring user variable declared in `Test plan` in user Defined variables node, just we can refer as `config_${version}.csv`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jp@gc - Parameterized Controller](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ParameterizedController/) for this.

Check the below snapshots

[image]

[image]

It;s up to you to use parameterized controller in place of UDV or combine them